# Unable to open STEP file in Inventor AutoDesk

Tags: 3d, autocad, autodesk, cad

I created a tool in Inventor and saved it in STEP format (2,63GB). Then I zipped it in order to share it with someone. Now we're unable to open it. When opening in Inventor it loads until 95% and then it stops loading or even crashes. Why is this?

I tried to unzip the file first and then open it but same result.

I also tried to open it using AutoCad Plant 3D using the command 'import'. But when I clicked on the step file to open it, AutoCad Plant 3D returned 'file not found'.

Answer (score 1):

Autodesk have acknowledged this issue, changing your active project to the Default project fixes this: https://www.autodesk.com/support/technical/article/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/Loading-or-Opening-a-step-file-in-Inventor-takes-a-long-time-and-or-hangs.html